# Blend DesignTime Data with d:IsDataSource

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

It seems that `d:IsDataSource` can be used to provide design time data in `blend`. Does anyone know where I can find the docs for this or can explain how the behavior and usage of this Property is? I have only seen it beeing used in a `ObjectDataProvider`. Where else can I use it and what does `blend` acutally do when it finds this property in a XAML element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing d:IsDataSource seems to define is whether it shows up as a datasource in the "Data" tab in blend. Correct me if I am wrong.